# Count rows and assign zero for NA observations in a specific column

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a data set containing ecological survey data on nine transects. Five quadrats were placed randomly along the length of each transect, and individuals within each quadrat were counted.  Here is a subset of the data:

```r
df <- structure(list(Date = c("8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/22/2022", "8/23/2022", "8/23/2022", "8/23/2022", "8/23/2022", "8/23/2022"), Transect.No = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Quadrat.No = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), Species = c("CUNN", "CUNN", "DOL", "DOL", "CUNN", NA, "CUNN", "CUNN", "CUNN", "CUNN", "CUNN", "CUNN", "CUNN", NA, NA, "FLOU", "DOL", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
head(df)
```

```
       Date Transect.No Quadrat.No Species
1 8/22/2022           3          1    CUNN
2 8/22/2022           3          1    CUNN
3 8/22/2022           3          2     DOL
4 8/22/2022           3          2     DOL
5 8/22/2022           3          2    CUNN
6 8/22/2022           3          3    <NA>
```

An `NA` in the `Species` variable implies that there were zero individuals in the corresponding quadrat.  I am looking to create a new data frame with a variable `Abundance` counting the total number of individuals in each quadrat.  This new data frame would look like this:

[image]

I tried the following code, but it gives `Abundance = 1` for those quadrats with `Species = NA`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(Quadrat.No, Transect.No, Date, name = "Abundance")
```

I want `Abundance = 0` in that case.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a weighted counts with the `wt` argument in the dplyr `count` functionand use not missing Species as weight

```
df %>%
  count(Quadrat.No, Transect.No, Date,wt=!is.na(Species), name= "Abundance") 

   Quadrat.No Transect.No      Date Abundance
1           1           3 8/22/2022         2
2           1           5 8/23/2022         0
3           2           3 8/22/2022         3
4           2           5 8/23/2022         0
5           3           3 8/22/2022         0
6           3           5 8/23/2022         1
7           4           3 8/22/2022         2
8           4           5 8/23/2022         1
9           5           3 8/22/2022         5
10          5           5 8/23/2022         0
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `sum` with `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  summarise(abundance = sum(ifelse(is.na(Species), 0, 1)), .by=c(Quadrat.No, Transect.No, Date))

   Quadrat.No Transect.No      Date abundance
1           1           3 8/22/2022         2
2           2           3 8/22/2022         3
3           3           3 8/22/2022         0
4           4           3 8/22/2022         2
5           5           3 8/22/2022         5
6           1           5 8/23/2022         0
7           2           5 8/23/2022         0
8           3           5 8/23/2022         1
9           4           5 8/23/2022         1
10          5           5 8/23/2022         0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `reframe`

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
 df %>% 
  reframe(abundance = sum(complete.cases(Species)), 
  .by = c(Quadrat.No, Transect.No, Date))
```

-output

```
    Quadrat.No Transect.No      Date abundance
1           1           3 8/22/2022         2
2           2           3 8/22/2022         3
3           3           3 8/22/2022         0
4           4           3 8/22/2022         2
5           5           3 8/22/2022         5
6           1           5 8/23/2022         0
7           2           5 8/23/2022         0
8           3           5 8/23/2022         1
9           4           5 8/23/2022         1
10          5           5 8/23/2022         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Identifying `NA`s before summarizing

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0, < 1.1.0 use group_by

df %>% 
  mutate(na = is.na(Species)) %>% 
  summarize(Abundance = unique(ifelse(na, 0, n())), 
    .by = c(Date, Quadrat.No, Transect.No))
        Date Quadrat.No Transect.No Abundance
1  8/22/2022          1           3         2
2  8/22/2022          2           3         3
3  8/22/2022          3           3         0
4  8/22/2022          4           3         2
5  8/22/2022          5           3         5
6  8/23/2022          1           5         0
7  8/23/2022          2           5         0
8  8/23/2022          3           5         1
9  8/23/2022          4           5         1
10 8/23/2022          5           5         0
```

older `dplyr` versions < 1.1.0

```
df %>% 
  mutate(na = is.na(Species)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Quadrat.No, Transect.No) %>% 
  summarize(Abundance = unique(ifelse(na, 0, n())), .groups = "drop")
```

Comment: For some reason R is throwing me an error when I try to run this code: "Caused by error in `if_else()`: `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector."